# How to add a property to my object using a map

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I want to add this "visible" attribute and change my "countries" array, "el2" is being changed correctly, but my array at the end is not as expected.

The elements are entering the conditionals and being added to the new property, but at the end of the loop the array is not coming out as expected

```
      const countryVisible: any = ['EUA', 'CANADA']
      const countries: any = [{name: 'EUA', id: '123'}, {name: 'CANADA', id: '321'}, {name: 'Italia', id: '322'}]

      countries.map((el2, index2) => {
        countryVisible.forEach((el, index) => {
          if (el2['name'] === el) {
             el2 = {...el2, visible: true}
            console.log(el2) // {name: 'EUA', id: '123', visible: true} and {name: 'CANADA', id: '321', visible: true}
          } else {
            el2 = {...el2, visible: false}
            console.log(el2) //{name: 'Italia', id: '322', visible: false}
          }
        })

      })

      console.log(countries)
```

output:

```
[
    {
        "name": "EUA",
        "id": "123"
    },
    {
        "name": "CANADA",
        "id": "321",
        "visible": false
    },
    {
        "name": "Italia",
        "id": "322",
        "visible": false
    }
]
```

output expected :

```
[
    {
        "name": "EUA",
        "id": "123",
        "visible": true
    },
    {
        "name": "CANADA",
        "id": "321",
        "visible": true
    },
    {
        "name": "Italia",
        "id": "322",
        "visible": false
    }
]
```

Comment: Why are you using the `any` type? Just omit it and TS will use type-inference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `forEach` loop with [.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method

```js
const countryVisible = ['EUA', 'CANADA'];
const countries = [{name: 'EUA', id: '123'}, {name: 'CANADA', id: '321'}, {name: 'Italia', id: '322'}];

const result = countries.map((country) => ({
  ...country, 
  visible: countryVisible.includes(country.name),
}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

There are minor issues with your code; two issues (maybe 3):

- You do not have a `return el2;` in the `map` method
- You do not assign the result back to `countries`, and hence,
- The variable `countries` should be declared with a `let`

And then, there's a major issue:

- Since you're setting the state of `visible` based on `countryVisible` array instead of based on the country object being considered, a visible state can be set to `false` even though it was set to `true` the first time. Eg. `EUA` will be set to `false` in the final result.
- In other words instead of checking and setting each country object just once, each is checked as many times as there are country objects.

```js
const countryVisible = ['EUA', 'CANADA'];
let countries = [{name: 'EUA', id: '123'}, {name: 'CANADA', id: '321'}, {name: 'Italia', id: '322'}];

countries = countries.map((el2, index2) => {
   if( countryVisible.includes( el2['name'] ) ) {
       el2 = {...el2, visible: true};;
   } else {
      el2 = {...el2, visible: false};;
   }
   return el2;
});

console.log(countries);
```

A better approach:

Consider using `map` and just adding the `visible` property to the mapped element.

```js
const countryVisible = ['EUA', 'CANADA'];
const countries = [{name: 'EUA', id: '123'}, {name: 'CANADA', id: '321'}, {name: 'Italia', id: '322'}];

const output = countries.map(
    ({name,id}) => 
    ({name,id,visible:countryVisible.includes(name)})
);

console.log( output );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax to assign conditional property to JS object. (ES6)

```
const a = {
   ...(someCondition && {b: 5})
}
```

Or you can use Javascript Object.defineProperty built-in function

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'foo', {
  value: 1
})
```